# Admob banner partially invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, google-play-services

Applicaion uses Google Play Services to show ad to user. But it shows only part of it.
It looks like

[image]

After a while banner (the next one) becomes full size.

[image]

What can be a reason of such behavior? DrawerLayout, appcompat ActionBar...? I'm not sure this issue came with the Google Play Services instead of admob lib. There are no overlapping elements in a layout.

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/content_search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.dimetil.gost.fragment.SearchFragment"
                android:tag="SearchFragment" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/content_favorites"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.dimetil.gost.fragment.FavoritesFragment"
                android:tag="FavoritesFragment" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/content_gost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.dimetil.gost.fragment.GostFragment"
                android:tag="GostFragment" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:indeterminateOnly="true"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try `SMART_BANNER` for the `adSize` and see if that helps at all.  I've had more success with banners that way with sizes. `ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"`

Comment: ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" did not help

Comment: May I ask why you have  android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of "wrap_content"??

Comment: Google recommends to use layout parameters this way https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration?hl=ru#create-adview-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has no solution. It is device or custom OS issue (Huawei G300/Cyanogen mode 11/Android 4.4.4).
I've seen other damaged ads on this device too.